# A man is on block 2, find expected number of steps for him to reach block 1.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> There are infinite blocks placed along positive axis at integer points. A man is on position $2$. He moves back one step with probability $p$ and forward with probability $1-p$ where $p > 0.5$.
>   Find expected number of steps for him to reach first block.

I denoted expected number of steps to reach block $1$ when on ith block as $E_i$

Then $E_1 = 0$ and we need to find $E_2$. Further there is a relation:

$$E_k = p(E_{k-1}+1)+(1-p)(E_{k+1}+1)$$

Now I dont have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a step forward, notice how the situation is similar, if you now ask the expected number of steps to return to tile $2$. So it will also take $E_2$ steps on average to go back to tile $2$ when you're on tile $3$, and then again $E_2$ to go from $2$ to $1$.  So we can write

$$E_2 = p\times 1 + (1-p)\times(1+2E_2)$$

and solve

$$E_2 = \frac{1}{2p-1}$$

We need to know that the expectancies are finite (which is the case when $p>0.5$), for this to make sense. For more information [see here](http://www2.math.uu.se/~sea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf).

Comment: Yes now I understand, it was this observation that simplifies it!